# Cannot reset the Windows DNS cache

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, dns, ip

I updated the DNS record for a certain website yesterday, but right now I'm facing an issue regarding my own computer's DNS cache, since I keep getting the old server's IP address when trying to access my site. Issuing `ping` or `nslookup` confirms that my DNS is not updated.

I am sure this is an issue with my computer, because I get the right IP address when using the router's *ping* tool, as well as my Android phone and a couple of virtual machines.

I've tried:

- `ipconfig /flushdns` (from command prompt with admin rights)
- Stopping and restarting the `dnscache` service
- Restarting the computer
- Zeroing the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file
- Manually setting the DNS server in my network adapter's properties to my ISP's DNS provider and also Google DNS and OpenDNS.

What is going on, and how can I fix this? I'm using Windows 10 64-bit.

---

**Update:** I deleted my virtual network switch from the Hyper-V manager and my DNS cache went back to normal.

Then I restarted the computer and created a new virtual switch, and this caused the old cache to take place again.

So I found the culprit, but not the solution - I do need the virtual switch to access the internet from my VMs.

Comment: I think you meant to say `nslookup` instead of `dnslookup`.

Comment: Try running ipconfig /registerdns on the machine thats getting the OLD ip address from an elevated command prompt. Run a ipconfig /flushdns from other machine to flush the dns cache with the wrong entry, finally try to ping the hostname again.

Comment: @doenoe I did that, still no success

Comment: It might be helpful to run [Nirsoft's DNSQuerySniffer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dns_query_sniffer.html), which shows the details of all DNS queries.

Comment: Did you flush the DNS _after_ you changed the DNS servers?

Comment: @boot13 Ah cool to know, indeed it appears that Nirsoft has a handy tool for everything!

Comment: What kind of VMs are you running? Is a DNS server among them? That server might still have that old record or maybe even a static entry.

Comment: @Seth Definitely not, one is Windows 10 Home Edition and the other was windows 7 Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted in the update to the question, this was a bug in the network switch implemented by the Hyper-V stack (on host-side).

There appears to be no solution. Maybe, just maybe, "re-installing" Hyper-V could work. But I wouldn't count on it.